# Inability to display image after deployment to Azure server but works in localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, permissions

I am having difficulty displaying images after deploying to Azure. 
I am currently developing my application on ASP.NET MVC 5. 
My methodology is for admin to upload a particular image, which would be accessible by users. The image is to be uploaded into a folder.

The issue is that I am able to get the image upload and displaying to work in my own localhost. However, it failed to work when I publish my app to Azure.

I have tried with many of the suggestions found in stackoverflow. 
[image]

E.g. Changing the Permission settings in the folder, but up to no avail.

I have attached my code for reference. I appreciate any help! =D

**Controller (file upload):**

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                try
                {
                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ExerciseImagesDepository"),
                                                   Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    ExerciseImage eI = new ExerciseImage();
                    eI.ExerciseID = ex.ExerciseID;
                    eI.ImageURL = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    db.ExerciseImages.Add(eI);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    ViewBag.FileUploadErrorMessage = "ERROR:" + exc.Message.ToString();
                }
```

**Controller (Details display)**

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        List<ExerciseViewModel> evmLIst = new List<ExerciseViewModel>();
        int a = 0;
        List<Exercise> exercise = db.Exercises.ToList();
        foreach (var item in exercise)
        {
            ExerciseViewModel evm = new ExerciseViewModel();
            a = a + 1;
            evm.ExerciseViewModelID = a;
            evm.ExerciseRegion = db.ExerciseRegions.Find(item.ExerciseRegionID);
            evm.ExerciseDescription = item.Description;
            evm.ExerciseType = db.ExerciseTypes.Find(item.ExerciseTypeID);
            int ExerciseID = item.ExerciseID;
            ExerciseVideo ev = db.ExerciseVideos.Where(m => m.ExerciseID == ExerciseID).SingleOrDefault();
            evm.VideoURL = ev.VideoURL;
            ExerciseImage ei = db.ExerciseImages.Where(m => m.ExerciseID == id).SingleOrDefault();
            if (ei != null)
            {
                evm.ImageURL = ei.ImageURL;
            }
            else
            {
                evm.ImageURL = "No Image Is Available For This Exercise";
            }
            evm.Exercise = item.Name;
            evmLIst.Add(evm);

        }
```

**View**

```
<div>
<p> TESTING HERE @Html.Raw(Model.ImageURL) </p>
<img src="~/ExerciseImagesDepository/@Html.Raw(Model.ImageURL)"/>
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

Comment: where are you storing your images?? another folder that you created or is it in images folder

Comment: I stored my folder in my root directory. I added a screenshot for reference. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I assume the directory is ExcerciseImagesDirectory. this is what i found after i publish to azure it sometimes does not create folders that are not default to th solution. now my experience with this is limited. when i started storing in the default images folder flat the images started appearing. or create the folder ExcerciseImagesDirectoryfrom the azure admin panel( this i have not tried since my need was simple i used images directory)

Comment: Could you direct me on how to create the folder ExerciseImageDirectory from the azure admin panel? I am really at my wits end. I even allow the   full control access to IIS APPPOOL\<myappname> in the properties settings page but to no avail

Comment: as i said i have not tried this but this could be a possible solution http://scottge.net/2015/08/03/how-to-deploy-to-the-virtual-directory-in-an-azure-website/

Answer (score 0):

I solve it! I figured that perhaps folder that are not default in the MVC 5 framework might be causing the issue. So instead, I created a new folder within the content directory and added a folder inside. Next, I tried changing that particular folder permission settings by adding a group or usernames "IUSR" and allowing full control. I then published the particular folder specifically to Azure and it works. Although I have no idea why I manage to do it.